# VBA/Powerpoint: How can I list which slides belong to any existing slide masters?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm a complete beginner with VBA and learning from existing macros and lots of Google searches.

I would like to generate a message box that lists the slide master name and the slides that use that master for each master in the presentation. Like this:

SlideMaster1: `1, 2, 5, 7`

SlideMaster2: `3, 4, 6, 8`

SlideMaster3: `No slides`

I have been working with some code for enumerating Designs/Masters from http://skp.mvps.org/designs.htm and it's very rough and basic right now.

```
Sub ListSlidesinMasters()

Dim lCtrA As Integer
Dim oPres As Presentation

Set oPres = ActivePresentation
With oPres
        For lCtrA = 1 To .Designs.Count
         MsgBox "Number of masters: " & .Designs.Count & vbCrLf & .Designs(lCtrA).Name & ": " & "unknown" & vbCrLf & "Slide # for active slide: " & ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex

    Next lCtrA
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
Sub Thing()
    Dim oMaster As Design
    Dim oPres As Presentation
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim sTemp As String

    Set oPres = ActivePresentation

    For Each oMaster In oPres.Designs

        sTemp = sTemp & oMaster.Name & vbTab

        For Each oSl In oPres.Slides
            If oSl.Design.Name = oMaster.Name Then
                sTemp = sTemp & CStr(oSl.SlideIndex) & ", "
            End If
        Next

        sTemp = sTemp & vbCrLf

    Next

    Debug.Print sTemp

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Glad it helped, @elidan